# How to send a file back from server to client?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, socket.io

I have to implement a client-server application in which the client has to send a text file with data. The server has to receive the file, correct the misspelled words, and then return the file to the client.

I can now successfully send a file from client to server and I am able to correct the spelling. Now, I am not sure how to send the file back from the server to the client.

Here is my current code:

Client:

```
def readFile(self):
        global f
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = [('txt', '*txt')])

        # filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir= "C://Users//Desktop//assignments//spellcheck-master")

        fileHandle = open(filename, 'r')
        for i, line in enumerate(fileHandle.readlines()):
            # import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
            message = (f"{self.name}: {line}") 
            client.send(message.encode(FORMAT))  

        fileHandle.close()
```

Server:

```
def handle(self, conn, addr):
            # receive the file infos
        # receive using client socket, not server socket
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        received = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode(FORMAT)
        filename, filesize = received.split(SEPARATOR)
        # remove absolute path if there is
        filename = "/Users/Desktop/Distributed_System/spellcheck/convertextTxt.txt"
        # convert to integer
        filesize = int(filesize)
        
        # start receiving the file from the socket
        # and writing to the file stream
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        while True:
            # read 1024 bytes from the socket (receive)
            bytes_read = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
            if not bytes_read:
                print("Nothing received")
                # nothing is received
                # file transmitting is done
                break
            # write to the file the bytes we just received
            rtf = bytes_read.decode(FORMAT)
            text = rtf_to_text(rtf)
            convertedTxt = self.spellCheck(text) 
            f.write(convertedTxt)
            f.close()
```

Now, how to send the converted file back from server to client?

Comment: Post your existing code so that we can comment on it.

Comment: On the server side, you already accept() the socket and recv() the text from it. Use the same socket to send() your reply back.

Comment: Updated code in the question please take a look.

Comment: have you tried adding at the end a line like:   conn.send(convertedTxt)

Comment: Yeah still it is not working.